# General setup for Nunit testing in ASP.NET webapplication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, nunit

Coming from Java programming, I'm used to the general Main<->Test Maven-setup for a project.
Whenever there's a new build, all tests will be run by Maven/Junit and I get feedback about them.

I've been looking around and I can't find an analogue way for ASP.NET and Nunit.
Am I forced to put my UnitTest-classes in the APP_Code folder?

What's the general way to do this? Are there any recommendations for continuous integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to architect a TDD-able web app is to put all your code in codebehinds; no inline ASP. Make the controls in the codebehind classes public, and develop your logical operations (bind/unbind, maybe) via TDD. As long as you can see the control and its children from outside the assembly, the unit tests can go anywhere.

Also consider an MVC setup; doesn't have to be the actual MVC framework of .NET, but if you strip down the codebehind to the absolute bare minimum, and perform all your logic in a controller class, then you can provide a mock page/codebehind for unit-testing the controller logic.

Comment: Ok thank you. I suppose when I deploy my website there's an option to deselect the Unit Test folder (which I'll be creating in App_Code).

Comment: Yes. In the Configuration Manager, you can set up build configurations. For your push to a production environment, don't include your tests.

Comment: If you're using the latest VisualStudio u can use the built-in unit testing framework and do without nUnit altogether. Ur tests will be contained within a separate project which u exclude from the release. This should get u up and running: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: There's no problem with using NUnit here either; if he's familiar with NUnit and is already using it then there's no reason to switch. As with MSTest, the NUnit tests can go in a separate project which is only compiled in Debug configuration.